# How To Get user name MVC for Represent in a PermisoAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a `PermisoAttribute` like this

```
public class PermisoAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
        {
            public string username { get; set; }
            public int ProgramId { get; set; }
            public int ModuleId { get; set; }

            public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
            {
                base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

                if (!permisos(this.username,this.ProgramId,this.ModuleId))
                {
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
                    {
                        controller = "Home",
                        action = "Denegado"
                    }));
                }
            }
        }
```

and this use permisos for know if the user have permission or not, that class return true o false. But when I use the PermisoAttribute in the controller a recive the behavior error

> Error CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property 'Controller.User'

I use the permissoAttribute like this

```
[HttpGet]
[Permiso(username = User.Identity.Name, ModuleId = 3, ProgramId = 2)]
public ActionResult Transactions()
{
  //do something here 
}
```

I use this code `User.Identity.Name` for send the user to the PermisoAttribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change ActionFilterAttribute for don't received a user name Like this

```
  public class PermisoAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
        {
            public string username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name; // { get; set; }
            public string Program { get; set; }
            public string Module { get; set; }

            public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
            {
                base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

                if (!permisos(this.username, this.Program, this.Module))
                {
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
                    {
                        controller = "Home",
                        action = "Denegado"
                    }));
                }
            }
        }
```

and get user name with `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` and for call PermisoAttribute just send  `[Permiso(Module = "modulename", Program = "programaname")]`